# Is there a way to sort specified records in a GridView/DataView, rather than the WHOLE table?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, dataview

For example, would I be able to sort rows with index 0 till 9, and rows 10 till 15 will remain unsorted? Is this possible?

If so, could someone suggest ways by which this may be accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your datasource yourself by any custom criteria you may have, before the data bind.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible due to strict requirements. The data source is a DataTable, which cannot be manipulated. What I've been doing to sort is placing the contents of the DataTable within a DataView, and sorting from there. Is it possible to sort specific rows in the DataView?

Comment: @Sean make a local copy of the data table, sort and bind to that?

Comment: I'll see if that's acceptable vis-a-vis the requirements I've been given. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom datatype which has a private `List<T>` as the underlying datastructure. You can do all sorting in you custom datatype so it's encapsulated and reusable.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [SortCompare Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare.aspx) to do a sorting that would fit your requirement. However, this will work only if the DataSource Property is not set.